# Click on row to pre-populate form with it's data only shows first record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have **hound_view.php** which displays the records based on search/filter criteria. When a user clicks on a row, a modal is displayed with a form for editing the hound info, which I want to be pre-populated based on the row that was clicked.

When a row in **hound_view.php** is clicked **hound_record_click_event.js** sends it's data-id to **fill_hound_records.php** where the database is queried and each row of data is assigned a variable to then pass to the modal in **edit_hound_records.php**

My issue is that when I click on any row, I am only getting the very first row's data to populate, but in **fill_hound_records.php** I echo back the variable to be sure each row is capturing its correct info and it is.

[image: visualized error]

**Please Note: This code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and should not be copied directly. You should use [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).**

**hound_view.php**

```
  <tbody class="clickable-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['RegNumber'] ?>">
```

**hound_record_click_event.js**

```
 $(window).ready(function() {
      //bind the event using jquery not the onclick attribute of the button
      $('.clickable-row').on('click', updateClick);
 });

 function updateClick() {
  var dataid = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax ({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "fill_hound_record.php",
         data: { dataid : dataid },
         success: function( result ) {
                alert(result);
         }
     });
 };
```

**fill_hound_record.php**

```
<?php
//include database configuration file
include('db.php');

$hounddataid = $_POST["dataid"];

//get rows
$prefillsql = "SELECT * FROM Hounds WHERE RegNumber = '$hounddataid'";
$prefillquery = mysqli_query($con,$prefillsql)or die(mysql_error());
$prefillnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($prefillquery);

if($prefillnumrows > 0){

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($prefillquery)){

    $prefillbreed = $row['Breed'];
    $_SESSION['pfbreed'] = $prefillbreed;
    $prefillregnumber = $row['RegNumber'];
    $_SESSION['pfregnumber'] = $prefillregnumber;

    echo $_SESSION['pfregnumber'];
}}
?>
```

**edit_hound_record.php**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="regnumber" name="regnumber" placeholder="Reg Number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pfregnumber']; ?>">
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am aware and plan on going back to correct this as this is my first production scale mysql/php project and am learning much as I go.

Comment: _"plan on going back"_ Don't get into the bad habit of thinking that. Write it correctly from the start, it's not like it takes any additional effort.

Comment: Though I agree, I didn't initially have knowledge or I would have done it in the first place, hence why I said I plan on going back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else with a similar problem; In **fill_hound_record.php** I added an if statement before the *$hounddataid* variable so I don't receive an undefined index before a row is clicked.

```
if (isset($_POST["dataid"])) { 
  $hounddataid = $_POST["dataid"];
  ...
  }
```

---

I removed the value attribute in **edit_hound_record.php** and in **fill_hound_record.php** I created an array of all the values I will need for populating the form and encoded in json.

```
$arr = array(
  'breed'=>$prefillbreed,
   ...
   );

echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

---

Finally I added

```
dataType: 'json',
 success: function( data ) {
    $("#breed").val(data.breed);
    ...
    }
```

to my **hound_record_click_event.js** which sends the selected json array value *data.breed* to the field in the form with an id of *breed*.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no info about boostrap version and if the table is generated with a plugin or not, I would suggest you to change this line:

```
<tbody class="clickable-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['RegNumber'] ?>">
```

with:

```
<tbody class="clickable-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
```

The data-id is the current second cell text of clicked row. In order to get this value you can use:

```
$(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text()
```

```js
$(window).ready(function () {
    //bind the event using jquery not the onclick attribute of the button
    $('.clickable-row').on('click', updateClick);
});

function updateClick(e) {
    var dataid = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "fill_hound_record.php",
                data: {dataid: dataid},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#editModal').find('.modal-body p').text(dataid);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Breed</th>
        <th>Reg Number</th>
        <th>Call Name</th>
        <th>Reg Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="clickable-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
    <tr>
        <td>AH</td>
        <td>024193</td>
        <td>Nia</td>
        <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AH</td>
        <td>022222</td>
        <td>Nia</td>
        <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="editModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This feels cleaner and will use, but I am still at the same exact point. Alert shows correct id for each row which is echoed in **fill_hound_record.php**, but when assigned to session variable and called in **edit_hound_records.php** it only returns that first rows id in the RegNumber field.

Comment: @TylerS.Smith Because alert print the correct value you need to set this value in the corresponding field: $('#regnumber').val(result). I created only a demo in order to help you. I hope this could help you more. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: @TylerS.Smith Like you can see I added a modal fragment at the end, instead you create it in PHP. The final html page should be similar.

Comment: How would I target the input field #regnumber if it goes php1 to js to php2 to php3 where php3 holds the modal.

Comment: @TylerS.Smith How do you show the modal? I assume with your data-target="#editModal". If you do it in a different way you can use the modal events: [show.bs.modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, with data-target on tbody.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your `<tbody>` is meant to be a table row `<tr>`

```
<tbody class="clickable-row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['RegNumber'] ?>">
```

Second, in your JS, you want to get the data-id:

```
 $(this).attr("data-id") // will return the string "123"
```

or .data() (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```
$(this).data("id") // will return the number 123
```

Comment: tbody and tr have the same results, tbody could technically be omitted if attributes were moved to tr. And $(this).data("id") is assigned to var dataid. The data-id is correct all the way through when echoing back from fill_hound_record.php, but when it comes to actually filling the form it only populates the first rows data-id.

Comment: Okay, can you post some sample HTML table rows from the DOM after the PHP has rendered the ID's etc?

Answer (score 0):

Error in your java script.  Change

```
    $(this).data ('id') to $(this).attr ('id')
```